# most efficient way to search object in NSMutableArray and remove redundant Values

Tags: ios, algorithm, search, nsmutablearray, duplicates

I have some arrays and all the arrays have redundant strings. now I have to remove redundant strings from then arrays but I can't afford brute force technique in my scenario. is there any efficient way to remove redundant values from an array?

Comment: should every array contain lokal-unique or global-unique values? Is the order of the Elements important?

Comment: local unique values and order is not important

Comment: Than i suggest the first Answer from @Jimpic, i dont think sorting the array is a good solution, but that depends on the data and you have to test wich approach is faster in your special case. Short Inline code: `[[NSSet setWithArray:arrayWithDuplicates] allObjects]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of NSSet is that uses the isEqual and hash method.
Some alternatives:

**1. Override NSString and implement hash and isEqual:**

This case you'd get your set without duplicated if in the isEqual method you return the result of caseInsensitiveCompare;

**1. Capitalize all the strings  and go ahead creating the set.**

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what exactly you need in the end. If you need a new array containing all input arrays values without duplicates, you can add all objects into a NSSet. A set will ignore added duplicates.

If you need the original arrays excluding duplicates, the best way would be to sort each of them and then recurse through each of them, removing duplicates.

Comment: thanx @jimpic it work for me but the problem is that NSSet is case sensitive. for example i have two string one is "one" and second is "ONE" then it will consider them separately